# Hand history posting limitations

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hand-history-questions

When I first committed to this beta, the potential that I envisioned it having with regard to in depth hand history discussion is close to perfect. The rating system is unique and will allow for a far greater emphasis on quality and not quantity (like many other forums!).

That said, HH's are very subjective. People dumping their entire days activities across multiple posts will get tiresome very quickly. Can we please institute some limits on the frequency with which people can post hands? 2 a day? 5 a day? 10 a day?

This may not be entirely optimal now, but once we're past private beta (or until it's common sense to do so), setting some pre-emptive ground rules would be beneficial.

Comment: this makes no sense. If someone asks very good questions, why couldnt they ask even a hundred a day ?
Bad quality questions won't live long anyway.

Comment: @Walkman I wouldn't go as far as saying it makes no sense. I 've spent a lot of time on other high traffic poker forums and it's a real issue. That said you've made a good point and reminded me that [poker.se].[SE] is a very different *type* of forum software, and yes, it's most likely these poor questions will be edited, revised, voted on, or closed etc until they fit this forums needs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a limit at every Stack Exchange site of 30 questions per user per day.  Aside from that, it would seem to go against how SE works to artificially limit the number of questions that a user can ask of a certain type.  If they are good questions, by all means they should stay (and please vote them up!).  If they are not good questions, vote them down (vote to close if appropriate).  Moderators and/or high rep users (who come closer to moderators as rep increases) can handle specific issues as they come up, but we don't need a limiting policy to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about "hand history" questions, but if what you are saying is true (I'm not saying it is or it isn't), therein lies a problem. You should not accept highly-subjective, easy-to-ask, easy-to-answer questions. They should not be part of this site.

Telling yourself that a type of question is okay as long as it doesn't get asked too much runs afoul of how Stack Exchange is designed.

Consider why you are going to hate answering these questions over and over — They become repetitive and formulaic. The solution is to create a canonical answer that describe *how* you are answering these question and close these highly localized questions as a duplicate.

This is a microcosm of **why we discourage questions** asking for "lists of ideas" or "list of shopping recommendations." There's nothing inherently *wrong* with asking "What do you think about…?" but in this type of merit-based Q&A site, these types of questions  tend to become the low-hanging fruit that lowers the bar of entry to asking useful questions. Everyone has a story they would like to share, and there's no end of random opinion people are willing to pitch into the conversation. **What gets lost is any appeal to expertise.**

Subjective questions that anyone can answer with random opinion encourages a free-for-all glut that will thwart any appeal of expertise on the site. A stream of questions asking over and over, "What do you guys think? … What do you guys think? … What do you guys think?" will just as quickly fill with endless opinions. To me, **that's not building a cannon of knowledge. It's a discussion board**… and that's not what we do here.

Comment: So are you against hand history questions?  I don't think this site will survive without them.

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg No, not necessarily. I don't know enough to speak intelligently about the issue. But I do know that the proposed solution (to the *perceived* problem) is not the right way to go. Deciding whether there is *actually* a problem here falls to this community. I clarified my post to add that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Agreed. When (if?) the time comes, we can experiment with the right limitation to impose. I would think 5 a day is plenty.

We should maybe rather consider imposing this limit over a longer period, i.e. 30 a week or 100 a month, for days when one really has many interesting hand histories to discuss.

Lastly, perhaps implement a system whereby you can trade reputation points for permission to post hand history questions?

Comment: The idea about trading rep is interesting. Worth thinking about. As for a weekly or monthly limit I'm not so keen. Having a fresh recollection about a poker hand is invaluable, and although you could store a post (write it out in draft, keep it on file) the immediacy of daily limits seems better to me. Howver, I only have experience of dailies so I can't claim to be sure of my perspective :)